# Multiple websites on an unique GA4 account

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm working in a company which has multiple international websites and I wanted to asked you if it's more interesting to have just on Google Analytics 4 account for all the websites or should I keep an account for every website ?

We have currently 12 websites and it will grow this year so I want to setup the best things before all of this.

Thank you,

I tried to do an unique account for two websites but i can't split the metrics and the events were not working.

Answer (score 0):

You may create one **analytics google profile** using this link https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/provision/#/provision

BUT, I would create a separate account for every website. Otherwise it will probably create problems in the future reading data from API ( I mean in the back-end coding system), analysing the retrieved data since every time you need to filter based on the domain etc.
Plus, there are limitations for creating the customised dimensions and metrics. Of course, I suppose you are talking about separate businesses or better say, different clients.